# Sample size in logistic regression - ouput with R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, modeling

I think im missing smoething.

How I calculate the sample size from this output - ?

[image]

Comment: Sample size is your input, not your output.

Comment: Look up how it's related to the null degree of freedom.

Comment: @Misius The question is most likely homework.

Comment: no, its not hw. the hw is to create the model. I did it. I have the excel file and I know there is 89 observations. I just want to know how to calculate it handly

Comment: @Misius  no, its not hw. the hw is to create the model. I did it. I have the excel file and I know there is 89 observations. I just want to know how to calculate it handly

Comment: @ArnaudMortier no, its not hw. the hw is to create the model. I did it. I have the excel file and I know there is 89 observations. I just want to know how to calculate it handly

Comment: Do you want to calculate it based only the output without using the input data at all or do you want to know the sample size for further purposes? If the fromer, you need to look up how to connect the sample size to the degrees of freedom and number of coefficients. If the latter, then you already have your  sample size.

Comment: @Misius I come across questions that give me such output and I have to say what the sample size is. So I want to figure out how to calculate it manually without R

Comment: Then, as suggested, look up how to connect the sample size to the degrees of freedom and number of coefficients.

Comment: @Misius what connect? 85 + 4? thats it?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/277012/324942

Comment: @Misius i get confused

Comment: The relationship is in the very first line of the answer that I attached. So in your case, yes, 89 = 85 + 4

Comment: @Misius ok, but i see another regression model with 3  coefficients, and  135 degree of freedom and the lecture told us it has 136 observations

Comment: Unfrotunately, it is not possible to comment on what your lecturere told you without knowing the context. Degreess of freedom in a simple linear regression is always calculated as the sample size minus the number of parameters to estimate

Comment: @Misius i told about logistics regression......

Comment: Sorry, my bad, did not notice this. Then the output you have does not say anything about degrees of freedom as such, but for other parameters. You need to read this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113022/324942 (you can find the exact formulae at the very end of the answer). This coincides with what your lecturer told you, however, that contradicts the fact that you said your data has 89 observations. I would recommend you to be much more specific the next time you are posting the question, because it is simply not possible to answer without any kind of context.